# Attempted to divide by zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, odp.net

I'm using oracle data provider for .net :

Oracle.DataAccess.dll vesrion : 2.111.7.2

Now just fire a select all statement usind OracleDataAdapater to generate the BUG (Attempted to divide by zero)

```
Dim conn As new OracleConnection(sConnectionString)
Dim dt As New DataTable
conn.Open()
Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM employee", conn)
da.Fill(dt) 'Exception
```

but if i execute statement using OracleDataReader then It works fine e.g.

```
Dim conn As new OracleConnection(sConnectionString)

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(" SELECT * FROM employee")
cmd.Connection = conn
Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Load(dr)
```

Please Is there any scientific explanation ????

**my stack trace :**

```
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at MedicalComponent.DAL.Production.MEMBERS_DAL.dtMemberClaims(Nullable`1 MPD_MBR_ID, Nullable`1 MPD_PLC_ID, String MEMBER_SEGMENT, Nullable`1 P_CLAIM_NO, Nullable`1 P_FROM_DATE, Nullable`1 P_TO_DATE, Nullable`1 FinanicalYear, Nullable`1 P_CLAIM_TYPE, Nullable`1 P_STATUS, Nullable`1 P_BENEFIT_TYPE, Nullable`1 P_MST_BNF_ID, String MST_ICD_CODE, Nullable`1 P_MNT_PRV_ID, Boolean AllFamilyClaims, Int32 PAGE_SIZE, Int32 PAGE_NUMBER, String SORT, Int32& PAGE_COUNT) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MedicalInsurance\MedicalInsurance3.5\MedicalComponent\DAL\Production\MEMBERS_DAL.cs:line 3399
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: how many rows are in employee?

Comment: the inner exception gave me this error, "Attempted to divide by zero", and the number of records is not too much around 200 records, i tried to retrieve only 10 record i have the same problem

Comment: is there max size for number of columns to datatable in .net???

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1084931

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html